# Does java have a built in elementAt(stack s, int index) method?

Tags: java, methods, indexing, stack

Im pretty new to programming. I've been using python for a year or so and am fairly proficient, but just recently started dabbling in Java. I can't find any type of method for what I'm looking for but its hard for me to believe there wouldn't be a built-in for this. I need to find the element at a given index of a stack.

Comment: If you're looking at a specific index, then why would you want a stack?

Comment: Only because it's a HW assignment. I realize a stack would not be ideal for this. I actual have to define my own method, but i wanted to see if there was one I could compare my own to

Answer (score 2):

Since `java.util.Stack` is a subclass of `java.util.Vector` then the answer is yes, you can use `stack.elementAt(index)`

Answer (score 0):

If you look closely at Stack's methods, you'll see it inherits methods from other classes, so it has more than just the ones specifically defined for it:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html

Stack inherits methods from Vector, including `get(index)`: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#get(int)

Comment: Presume that Oracle's API were offline.  If both links were busted, then this answer would be very incomplete.  Could you flesh it out a bit more?

Answer (score 0):

Use Stack.elementAt(index) method.

There is no static method. Use index on the instance of the Stack class.
[java reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#elementAt%28int%29)